# MySQL UDF not found even though installation is OK

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I've created an extremely simple UDF on Windows that exports the function `set_named_event`, I can check the DLL to see the exported symbol(s) (_init + _deinit also), and I do (using MySQL Server 5.5 Community Edition):

```
USE `test`;
DROP FUNCTION set_named_event;
CREATE FUNCTION set_named_event RETURNS INTEGER SONAME "udf_set_named_event.dll";
```

which gives me no errors, however when I do:

```
SELECT set_named_event('eventName');
```

I get the infamous:

```
Query: SELECT set_named_event('eventName')

Error Code: 1305
FUNCTION test.set_named_event does not exist

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.003 sec
```

Ideas ?? Can it be that the CE of the server doesn't support UDFs ??

Comment: I presume `set_named_event` <> `set_named_function` is just a typo in your question?  Where have you placed the DLL (it should be in [`plugin_dir`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_plugin_dir))?

Comment: @eggyal: Yes, it's a typo, I'll change it. And yes, the DLL is placed in the folder defined by plugin_dir.